# Understanding Raw Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

When I was going through all the tables in my database, I could see a table called `Measbinary` and an attribute attracted me was `RawData`. Which is Image type and Allow null. I have attached a screenshot of the table Could someone help me understand what is that? and how could I understand How it has been processed ?

[image]

Update : I checked the stored procedures and could find that the image parameter is passed to it like 
SP_StoreBinary @rawspectra image
and then the value is inserted to the table mentioned above.

Comment: Looks like application-specific raw data, and there's no obvious clue (e.g. magic numbers) to the file format. You'll need to talk to whoever looks after whichever application uses the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the raw data of a binary field. It has "no meaning" except being a way for SSMS (Management Studio) to show SOMETHING for a binary field. Remember - SSMS (and the database) have no clue what is in that field (image, word document, whatever) and how to show it. A hex coded string is "as good as it gets" as a generic approach, as it allows a programmer to compare the first bytes.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Is there any way I could extract the information from it

Comment: RTFM. Seriously. It is binary data - your documentation (and I do not mean SQL Server, I mean whatever software was written on top of it) will know what data is stored there.There is a column named "RawDataType" - that likely goes to a lookup table with more information. WIthout knowing the software - we have no clue what is stored there.